# Safari Mobile - Crashing - Three JS Texture not loading up

Tags: javascript, ipad, 3d, mobile-safari, three.js

I am trying to create a spherical panorama using THREE.js. It works great on Safari Desktop but crashes on Safari Mobile on the iPAD. It has something to do with the way I'm loading up the texture image.

A few things I've tried

1. I'm using the Canvas Renderer
2. Tried loading up an image of a smaller size.
3. Tried loading up a power of 2 texture image.
4. Tried loading the Sphere with a wireframe material - It works!

Here's my code. 
http://pastebin.com/1nwTMHJV

```
sceneHolder = document.getElementById( 'sceneHolder' );
scene = new THREE.Scene();
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, SCENE_WIDTH / SCENE_HEIGHT, 1, 10000 );
camera.position.z = 0;
scene.add( camera );

var sphereGeom = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 200, 20, 20 );
//NOTE: If we add {},function(){render()} in the following, it stops working!
var sphereTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('media/vr/testpot.jpg');
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeom,new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:sphereTexture,overdraw:true}));
//So that we see the inside of the sphere too!
mesh.doubleSided=true;
scene.add( mesh );

renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
renderer.setSize(  SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT );
sceneHolder.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

Here's my post on THREE.js
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1529

Also: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1550

Thanks
smaira

Answer (score 0):

I tried, lowering number of faces can run on iPad, but it's just ugly.

you may try:

```
var sphereGeom = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 200, 10, 10 );
```

and the safari crash at the time of render

```
renderer.render( scene, camera );
```

conclusion:
if load image texture to sphere with too many faces, iPad will crash